# Partitions while installing Elementary OS

Tags: system-installation

I always installed Elementary by erasing the whole disc so the necessary partitions were created on their own. But in a lot of tutorials on the internet people were creating those partitions themselves.

Should I create them myself with specific values or erasing the disc and automate that procedure is ok?

Just to be clear I I am referring to the case of installing only one OS not dual booting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the partitions created by elementary os installer to be quite good. maybe you don't need the swap partition of you are not going to use hibernation , but other then that its OK.

BTW it's auto partitioning works for dual boot as well, u mean even if you are installing elOs as dual boot or can create the partitions for you